# Return different type based on passed parameter

Tags: swift, autolayout, uikit

I created a custom type with view's edges like these:

```
public enum Edge {

    //MARK: - Vertical Variables

    case top
    case bottom

    //MARK: - Horizontal Variables

    case left
    case right
}
```

And for now I want to create some kind of help method which will convert my enum to `NSLayoutXAxisAnchor` or `NSLayoutYAxisAnchor` based on `self`

```
func convertToNSLayoutAnchor(ofView view: UIView) -> NSLayoutXAxisAnchor or NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    switch self {
    case .top:
        return view.topAnchor
    case .bottom:
        return view.bottomAnchor
    case .left:
        return view.leftAnchor
    case .right:
        return view.rightAnchor
    }
}
```

Is there an elegant way to do these in one method using maybe generics or something else, without creating 2 different func?